# Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, RDIFF-BACKUP, data source and destination on remote machines

Tags: backup, port, remote-access, ubuntu-14.04, rdiff-backup

i've got a problem with rdiff-backup...

I have three systems:

System-A: Data source, SSH on port 1234

System-B: Backupspace, SSH on port 22

System-C: Executive system which runs rdiff-backup.

my rdiff-call is as follows:

```
SOURCE_PORT="1234"
SOURCE_USER="user_A"
SOURCE="System-A"
TARGET_PORT="22"
TARGET_USER="user_B"
TARGET="System-B"
#left out the variables for paths
# ...

rdiff-backup --create-full-path --no-hard-links \
--remote-schema=\'ssh -C %s \"sudo rdiff-backup --server\"\' \
'-p ${SOURCE_PORT} ${SOURCE_USER}@${SOURCE}'::${BACKUP_SOURCE_PATH}/${ADDITIONAL_FOLDER}/${BACKUP_NAME} \
'-p ${TARGET_PORT} ${TARGET_USER}@${TARGET}'::${BACKUP_TARGET_PATH}/${ADDITIONAL_FOLDER}/${BACKUP_NAME}
```

I hoped to get the -p parameter inside the userinfo for placeholder %s, but this won't work.
--remote-schema won't work either, because it can set one -p parameter like:

```
--remote-schema=\'ssh -p 1234 -C %s \"sudo rdiff-backup --server\"\'
```

Then System-A can be contacted, but connections to System-B fail...

I don't know what to do anymore...

Do someone know, how to tell rdiff-backup to use different ports for the remote data source and the remote backup destination?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, if it's a hack or a feature, but it seems that you can supply a quoted host_info, in which you can provide the port number and thus avoid to use --remote-schema.

For example:

> $ rdiff-backup /source/dir "-p 1234 user@host.com"::/remote/dir

HTH